# Array traversal repeat even numbers same array

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an exercise where I should repeat the even number inside the same array. So for example given the following array:

[1,2,5,6,8]

I should get:

[1,2,2,5,6,6,8,8]

I think I almost have the solution but there are two edge cases where they don't work:

[1,2,5,6,8,7,7,7]

or

[1,2,5,6,8,8,7,7]

This is my code:

```js
function repeatEvenNumbers(arr) {
    let end = arr.length -1;
    for(let i = arr.length -1; i > 0; i--){
      end = i;
      if(arr[i] % 2 === 0){
        if(i === arr.length -1){
          end+=2;
          arr[end] = arr[i];
          end+=1;
          arr[end] = arr[i];
        }else{
          end+=1;
          arr[end] = arr[i];
          if(i - 1 !== 0){
            end+=1;
            arr[end] = arr[i];
          }
        }
      }else{
        end+=1;
        arr[end] = arr[i];
      }
    }
    return arr;
}
// console.log(repeatEvenNumbers([1,2,3])) // [1,2,2,3]
console.log(repeatEvenNumbers([1,2,5,6,8])) // [1,2,2,5,6,6,8,8]
```

Comment: Are you deliberately avoiding copying the array or using javascript's many array helper functions for the purpose of the exercise? It would help to list such constraints so that the best answer can be given that helps you.

Comment: @Klaycon yes it must be on the same array

Comment: which array methods are you allowed to use?

Comment: @alex is Nuno's answer sufficient, then? it modifies the array as you request. if it solves your problem, remember to mark it as accepted

Comment: Would this be considered cheating? `ns => ns .flatMap (n => n % 2 ? n : [n, n]) .forEach ((n, i) => ns[i] = n` ? It modifies your initial array, but uses a helper array along the way to do so.

Comment: @ScottSauyet well in fact every built in function for arrays will be considered cheating. The most similar one perhaps although it uses splice could be Nuno's which doesn't create another array. What do you think?

Comment: That was mostly a joke.  I'm too much of an opponent of mutating data that I would not have bothered answering except that I already had a simplification to post to the answer from Max. Also note, as @Klaycon pointed out, you should note such extra requirements as not using the methods of `Array.prototype` in the question.

Comment: @alex Please see mine and Scott's answers for solutions that do not "cheat" with built in array functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments it has been clarified that this problem has these constraints:

- no creating other arrays
- no array helpers or built-ins

Your current solution isn't working because your code has absolutely no idea *how big the array will be* by the end of things. What if it's an array of 5 even numbers, so the last number will need to be shifted forward 5 spaces in the new array? There's nowhere that accounts for that, you'll only ever shift forward 2 spaces at most.

I suggest two passes, one to count even numbers and one to offset the elements exactly the required number of positions.

```js
function repeatEvenNumbers(arr) {
    let offset = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      if(arr[i]%2 === 0)
        offset++;
    for(let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
      if(arr[i] % 2 === 0) //for even numbers, set an additional element
        arr[i+offset--] = arr[i]; //and decrement offset going forward
      arr[i+offset] = arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(repeatEvenNumbers([1,2,5,6,8,8,7,7]))
```

This way you can arrive at the correct answer in `O(2n)` instead of needing an additional loop to shift all elements, which would be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Very nice.  I still would never choose something like this over the `flatMap`- or `reduce`- based solutions, but given the non-functional requirements, this is a nicer technique than mine.

Answer (score 4):

By using arr.splice("index to insert in array", "# of items to delete", "value to insert") you can insert a new value in the position you want. 
In this case it simplifies your task a lot.

```js
function repeatEvenNumbers(arr) {
    let end = arr.length -1;
    for(let i = end; i > 0; i--){
      if(arr[i] % 2 === 0){
        arr.splice(i, 0, arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return arr;
}
// console.log(repeatEvenNumbers([1,2,3])) // [1,2,2,3]
console.log(repeatEvenNumbers([1,2,5,6,8])) // [1,2,2,5,6,6,8,8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution is quite complicated and be rewritten in ways others have already shown you.

So you can do it with `reduceRight`:

```js
const repeatEven = arr => {
  return arr.reduceRight((acc, val, index) => {
    if (val % 2 === 0) acc.splice(index, 0, val)
    return acc
  }, arr)
}

console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,8,7]))
console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,6,8,7,7,7]))
console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,6,8,8,7,7]))
```

Or even better, as Scott Sauyet suggested:

```js
const repeatEven = arr => {
   return arr.flatMap(n => n % 2 ? n : [n, n])
}

console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,8,7]))
console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,6,8,7,7,7]))
console.log(repeatEven([1,2,5,6,8,8,7,7]))
```

Comment: you are creating an array @Max the whole purpose of the exercise is to do it on the same array

Comment: @alex: for heaven's sake, *why*?  :-)

Comment: Or even  more modern, `arr .flatMap (n => n % 2 ? n : [n, n])`.

Comment: because it's an exercise for top tech companies I know how to do it like you do :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Nuno's answer, but replacing the `splice` call with an additional loop to satisfy the additional requirement that none of the methods of `Array.prototype` is used.

```js
const dupEvens = (ns) => {
  for (let i = ns.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {
    if (ns[i] % 2 == 0) {
      for (let j = ns.length ; j > i ; j-- )  {
        ns[j] = ns[j - 1]
      }
    }
  }
  return ns
}

console.log(dupEvens([1,2,5,8,7]))
console.log(dupEvens([1,2,5,6,8,7,7,7]))
console.log(dupEvens([1,2,5,6,8,8,7,7]))
```

I would never suggest writing code this way without a very good reason.  The answer from Max (with or without my refinement) seems a much better solution to duplicating the even numbers in an array.

But if you also have to forgo the `Array.prototype` methods and have to mutate the original array instead of creating a new one, then this would work.

However, if a company asked me to do it like that in an interview, I would ask some very sharp questions about their development practices!

Answer (score 0):

You could take another temporary array and store the old values and double values and get the index wise values back to the original array.

```js
function doubleEven(array) {
    var temp = [];
    
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        temp.push(array[i]);
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) temp.push(array[i]);
        array[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (; i < temp.length; i++) array[i] = temp[i];

    return array;
}

console.log(...doubleEven([1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7]));
```